# Tooltip only working on one text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have the below code which I got from another website. The problem I am having is it is only displaying onclick of the first text field. All other textfields it does not work.

I have not bothered posting the CSS as not needed to fix I believe.

Basically to display a text field I have to place the below code right underneath each textfield

```
<span class="hint">This is a hint">&nbsp;</span></span>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      oldonload();
      func();
    }
  }
}

function prepareInputsForHints() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    // test to see if the hint span exists first
    if (inputs[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) {
        // the span exists!  on focus, show the hint
        inputs[i].onfocus = function () {
            this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
        }
        // when the cursor moves away from the field, hide the hint
        inputs[i].onblur = function () {
            this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
// repeat the same tests as above for selects
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (var k=0; k<selects.length; k++){
    if (selects[k].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) {
        selects[k].onfocus = function () {
            this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
        }
        selects[k].onblur = function () {
            this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
}
addLoadEvent(prepareInputsForHints);
```

I like the tooltip as it's exactly what I wanted as it shows a `<` (sideways triangle) so it points to the textbox that is selected.

I was thinking of maybe using jQuery but as I don't have knowledge of JS/jQuery not sure how I would make it so it uses the CSS I currently have for the tooltip.

Comment: Why do you have two closing tags on the `<span>`?  What does the rest of the markup around each `<input>` look like?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure it's basically the code for the tooltip, code i posted is the javascript and the html to show tooltip. Apart from that there is css for styling. I found it online.

Comment: Here's the link to the code: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/formfieldhints.shtml

Comment: Are you actually using jQuery? You included the tag, but there isn't any in your code.

Comment: why tagged `jquery` and `tools`?!

Comment: Hi it's not jquery to my knowledge just javscript. I entered jquery in as a tag incase someone recommended some jquery code which is better than javascript as better code.

Comment: from what I see, you are really bad in `copy/paste`!!

Comment: why do you say that? i simply copied and pasted there is nothing else to it.

Comment: because the markup (`spans`) here is **not** the same as the link you posted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your HTML markup. Each span/input pair must be in its own container.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/E7ZME/

```
<div><input><span class="hint">This is a hint"&nbsp;</span></div>
<div><input><span class="hint">This is a hint"&nbsp;</span></div>
<div><input><span class="hint">This is a hint"&nbsp;</span></div>
```

I didn't change any of the javascript you posted. I only used this HTML, and a little CSS.

**EDIT:**

If you're going to use jQuery, check out some of the tooltip plugins.

- http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html
- http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Here's a list of 30 of them:

- http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/